# How to Access DAC Extension on Action Delegate

Tags: acumatica

This is might be the stupid question, but it really bring me so much pain to figured. 
The requirement is to add Create Request button from Opportunity. perform validation to make sure that there is no Request ever created for current opportunity. I've added custom field UsrReqNbr on CROpportunity DAC to build  relationship between Opportunity and Request. Try all method to read Extension field using:

```
1. CROpportunityExt oppExt = opportunity.GetExtension<CROpportunityExt>();
2. CROpportunityExt oppExt = Base.Opportunity.Cache.GetExtension<CROpportunityExt>(opportunity);
3. CROpportunityExt oppExt = Base.Caches[typeof(CROpportunity)].GetExtension<CROpportunityExt>(opportunity);
```

but have no succeeds. kindly need advice about how to read DAC extension on Action Delegate

The code is define like follows:

```
public PXAction<PX.Objects.CR.CROpportunity> createRQRequest;

[PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Create Request")]
public virtual IEnumerable CreateRQRequest(PXAdapter adapter)
{
  foreach (CROpportunity opportunity in adapter.Get())
  {
    Customer customer = (Customer)PXSelect<Customer, Where<Customer.bAccountID, Equal<Current<CROpportunity.bAccountID>>>>.Select(Base, opportunity.BAccountID);
    if (customer == null)
    {
      throw new PXException("Prospect Not Customer");
    }


    CROpportunityExt oppExt = PXCache<CROpportunity>.GetExtension<CROpportunityExt>(opportunity);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(oppExt.UsrReqNbr))
    {
      throw new PXException("Yess, successfully read");
      RQRequest req = PXSelect<RQRequest,
        Where<RQRequest.orderNbr, Equal<Current<CROpportunityExt.usrReqNbr>>>>.Select(Base, oppExt.UsrReqNbr);

      if (req == null)
      {
        WebDialogResult result = Base.Opportunity.View.Ask(opportunity, PXMessages.LocalizeFormatNoPrefix("Create Request Confirmation"), PXMessages.LocalizeFormatNoPrefix("Create Request for this Opportunity?"), MessageButtons.YesNo, MessageIcon.Question);
        if (result == WebDialogResult.Yes)
        {
          oppExt.UsrReqNbr = null;
        }
      }
      else
      {
        WebDialogResult result = Base.Opportunity.View.Ask(opportunity, PXMessages.LocalizeFormatNoPrefix("Create Request Confirmation"), Messages.OrderView, MessageButtons.YesNo, MessageIcon.Question);
        if (result == WebDialogResult.Yes)
        {
          RQRequestEntry docgraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<RQRequestEntry>();
          docgraph.Document.Current = req;
          throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(docgraph, "");
        }
        throw new PXException(Messages.OrderAlreadyCreated);
      }
    }
    else
    { 
      throw new PXException("Nooo, can't read the extensions");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong or strange I noticed in your code. Any errors thrown when instance of the CROpportunity DAC extension is requested? Or your do you always get null instead of a DAC extension?

Time to time I experience weird things happening, I guess, because of how Acumatica runtime compilation and .Net runtime work. Usually restart of IIS helps to completely resolve issues such issues. Could you please restart IIS on your developer machine and update the question with additional details if issue remains?

Comment: I always get Null Value. Restart IIS already and still always got null value. Should I use AddHandler to RowSelected event to make the logic executed perfectly?

Comment: Okay, this is another weird things. After restarting IIS gives no effect, restarting the development server fixed the problem.